# Существует ли переменная окружения BASH?

Tags: bash

Задача: ввести имя переменной окружения и выяснить существует ли такая переменная. Мой код скрипта:

```
echo "Введите имя переменной окружения"
read name
if "$name" == env
then
echo "Переменная $name существует"
else
echo "Переменная $name не существует"
fi
```

но скрипт отрабатывает неверно мое решение. Понимаю, что неверно определено условие. Как составить условие на принадлежность переменной окружению?

Comment: [[ ${!name} ]] && printf "Переменная $name не пустая" || printf "Переменная $name пустая"

Comment: @PotroNik, или без башизмов: `[ -v "$name" ] && ...`

Comment: @0andriy  '-v' добавлено только в версии bash 4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Вариант 1

Использовать grep

```bsh
/usr/bin/env | grep "^${name}="
```

результат записать в переменную и проверять её на пустоту.

#### Вариант 2

Не используя `env` проверять просто текущее окружение

```bsh
if [ -v "${name}" ];
then
    echo "Переменная $name существует"
else
    echo "Переменная $name не существует"
fi
```

Ключ `-v` позволяет проверить существование переменной

Comment: спасибо!!! задача решена )))

Answer (score 1):

Еще пара вариантов:

```
read -p "Введите имя переменной окружения: " name
...
```

---

```
...
NAME="${!name:+Переменная $name не пустая}"
echo "${NAME:-Переменная $name пустая}"
```

---

```
...
if [[ ${!name} ]]
then
    echo "Переменная $name не пустая" 
else
    printf "Переменная $name пустая"
fi
```

---

**Не безопасно:**

```
...
eval NAME=\$$name
if [[ $NAME ]]
then
    echo "Переменная $name не пустая" 
else
    echo "Переменная $name пустая"
fi
```